# How to duplicate dictionary with 0 values

Tags: python, dictionary

What I can do:

```
dict1 = {'key1':0, 'key2':10, 'key3':110}
dict2 = dict(dict1)
for key in dict2:
    dict2[key] = 0

print(dict2) # {'key1':0, 'key2':0, 'key3':0}
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest, using `dict comprehension` :

```
>>> {k:0 for k in dict1}
```

# driver values :

```
IN : dict1 = {'key1':0, 'key2':10, 'key3':110}
OUT : {'key1':0, 'key2':0, 'key3':0}
```

Comment: Cannot believe I never tried using generators with dictionaries. Thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :D

Comment: @Alex that is not a generator, that is a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Yup. May look like it, but big difference between them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1':0, 'key2':10, 'key3':110}
>>> dict.fromkeys(dict1, 0)
{'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, 'key3': 0}
```

Be careful, though, if your fill-value is a mutable object, this will mean every value will be the same instance of that mutable object, e.g.:

```
>>> new_dict = dict.fromkeys(dict1, [])
>>> new_dict
{'key1': [], 'key2': [], 'key3': []}
>>> new_dict['key1'].append('foo')
>>> new_dict
{'key1': ['foo'], 'key2': ['foo'], 'key3': ['foo']}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if OP wants values starting from 0, it might be good to suggest the use of a `defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {'key1':0, 'key2':10, 'key3':110}
dict2 = dict((i,0) for i in dict1)
```

**Result**:

```
{'key3': 0, 'key2': 0, 'key1': 0}
```